# INSERT maintenance checklist table form PHP HTML MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i need to create a table to register maintenance made on safety devices of machines.

i have a table of my db that contains the list of all machines associated with theyr own safety devices.

each safety devices can be "OK" "NOT OK" "PARTYALLY OK" or "NA"

i have createad a webpage with HTML/PHP where the maintener select the machine on which he is doing the maintenance and it will appeare the list of the safety devices that he has to control and register the state of the device (ok, not ok...).

```
<html>
    <? include 'home.php' ?>    
        <body>
            <div>
                <form action="insert_controllo.php" method="POST">
                <table>
                    <th>Macchina</th>
                    <th>Dispositivo</th>
                    <th>Descrizione</th>
                    <th>OK</th> 
                    <th>NOK</th>    
                    <th>PARZ</th>   
                    <th>NA</th> 
                    <th>Note</th>   
<?                      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($risultato)){
                            echo "<tr><td>  <input class='hide' type= 'text' name='macc' value ='".$row['macc']."' readonly> 
                                  </td><td> <input class='hide' type= 'text' name='iddispssic' value ='".$row['iddispsic']."' readonly> 
                                  </td><td> <input class='hide' type= 'text' name='descgen' value ='".$row['descgen']."' readonly>
                                  </td><td> <input type= 'checkbox' name='chk1[]' value ='OK'>  
                                  </td><td> <input type= 'checkbox' name='chk1[]' value ='NOK'>
                                  </td><td> <input type= 'checkbox' name='chk1[]' value ='PARZ'>    
                                  </td><td> <input type= 'checkbox' name='chk1[]' value ='NA'> 
                                  </td><td> <input type='text' name='note' placeholder = 'Note'> 
                                 </td></tr>";   
                        }?>
                </table>
                <button class="bottone" name='submit' type='submit'>Concludi</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

my problem is that in the POST VAR DUMP i receive only the first row of the table

```
        <!-- POST: Array
(
    [macc] => 09
    [iddispssic] => 2
    [descgen] => Ripari Fissi
    [chk1] => Array
        (
            [0] => NOK
        )

    [note] => 
    [submit] => 
)
 -->
```

and i dont know how to INSERT in the DB the checkbox selected

can someone help me?

i would like to insert in the DB something like this

Machine-SafetyDevice-State(OK,NotOK,...)-description(there is an input type text to add note on each row)-DateTime

Comment: Are you trying to save multiple row into your table?. If so you require to play with array. My recommendation is you play with JSON array and stringnify it. Store it into your input text. Post it to your next PHP page, then Decode it into array again to do the insert for multiple rows.

Comment: yeah i have multiple row on my page beacuse each machine got a lot of safety devices.
each devices can be "ok,not ok,patially ok, na" (selected with a checkbox).

Comment: In the next form you can get the data with $_POST or $_REQUEST and then insert them in the database with mysqli or pdo

Comment: i have only 1 form that containt a tabel with the query result of the table DB with the association between machines and safety devices, in the POST i get only the first row of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the name of inputs to create an array of elements (you can change the "elements" name for another one).

```php
$count = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($risultato)){
  echo '<tr><td>  <input class="hide" type= "text" name="elements['.$count.'][macc]" value ="'.$row["macc"].'" readonly> 
    </td><td> <input class="hide" type= "text" name="elements['.$count.'][iddispssic]" value ="'.$row["iddispsic"].'" readonly> 
    </td><td> <input class="hide" type= "text" name="elements['.$count.'][descgen]" value ="'.$row["descgen"].'" readonly>
    </td><td> <input type= "checkbox" name="elements['.$count.'][chk1][]" value ="OK">  
    </td><td> <input type= "checkbox" name="elements['.$count.'][chk1][]" value ="NOK">
    </td><td> <input type= "checkbox" name="elements['.$count.'][chk1][]" value ="PARZ">    
    </td><td> <input type= "checkbox" name="elements['.$count.'][chk1][]" value ="NA"> 
    </td><td> <input type="text" name="elements['.$count.'][note]" placeholder = "Note"> 
    </td></tr>';   

  $count ++;
}
```

If only one state is allowed at the same time you must change the checkboxes to place a radio button, like this:

```php
$count = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($risultato)){
  echo '<tr><td>  <input class="hide" type= "text" name="element['.$count.'][macc]" value ="'.$row["macc"].'" readonly> 
    </td><td> <input class="hide" type= "text" name="element['.$count.'][iddispssic]" value ="'.$row["iddispsic"].'" readonly> 
    </td><td> <input class="hide" type= "text" name="element['.$count.'][descgen]" value ="'.$row["descgen"].'" readonly>
    </td><td> <input type= "radio" name="element['.$count.'][chk1]" value ="OK">  
    </td><td> <input type= "radio" name="element['.$count.'][chk1]" value ="NOK">
    </td><td> <input type= "radio" name="element['.$count.'][chk1]" value ="PARZ">    
    </td><td> <input type= "radio" name="element['.$count.'][chk1]" value ="NA" checked> 
    </td><td> <input type="text" name="element['.$count.'][note]" placeholder = "Note"> 
    </td></tr>';   

  $count ++;
}
```

In "insert_controllo.php" you can read the data this way:

```php
  if(isset($_POST['elements'])){
    for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['elements']); $i++){
      // the query. For example 'UPDATE TABLENAME SET chk1 = "'.$_POST['elements']['chk1'].'" WHERE macc = "'.$_POST['elements']['macc'].'" ';
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: i need to insert it into a table, how can i do it?
thanks in advance